# how can i position a button below two linear layouts(nested views) containted in a linear layout (root view)

Tags: java, android, xml

I know i can use relative layout but it seems a bit complicated, a lot of interactions between the views. I know i can also use constraint layout but for now i don't know how to use it yet.

My question is:

- Is there a way to put the button below the two linear layouts? ( occupying the same space due to the weight attribute  android:layout_weight="1")
- [This is an image of the layout I am trying to build.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl7Ja.png)
- This is the code I am using :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="@string/team_a"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text=""/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_3_points"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="points3"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="points2"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/_2_points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:onClick="freethrow"
                android:text="@string/free_throw" />
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:text="@string/team_b"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/team_a_score1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text=""/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/_3_points"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="points31"
                android:textAllCaps="true"/>

            <Button
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button21"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:onClick="points21"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:text="@string/_2_points" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button31"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:onClick="freethrow1"
                android:text="@string/free_throw" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Button" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but should work fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/team_a"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text=""/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_3_points"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="points3"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="points2"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="@string/_2_points" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:onClick="freethrow"
            android:text="@string/free_throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/team_b"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="175dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/team_a_score1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text=""/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/_3_points"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="points31"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/button21"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:onClick="points21"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:text="@string/_2_points" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button31"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:onClick="freethrow1"
            android:text="@string/free_throw" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Button" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank's a lot for your response. it doesn't work because of the orientation. it is true if we choose to align everything vertically the button is  on the ending of the parent. but the voting segments are one below the other and i want it one next to the other... i will try out the relative layout as the root view as well as the constraint layout